# Compress a file using Brotli client side

Tags: javascript, compression

My client need to upload some large text files to s3. We're speaking around 10-100 mb each.
The files show an exceptional compression ratio using brotli (around 90% compression), but I couldn't find a cross-platform way to compress files before upload in the browser:

- I thought of using `CompressionStream`, but it's not supported by firefox and it doesn't support brotli
- I thought of using `TransformStream`, but I don't know how to brotli compress the content

The only solution I can see is to use a wasm polyfill like [this](https://github.com/httptoolkit/brotli-wasm), even though I know browsers support brotli. Is there a way to brotli compress a file without using polyfills?